# Calculate the total time in Seconds

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have a field in my table which has the time for a particular action. The entries are like 
`00:01:29` 
`00:02:12` 
`00:00:45` etc...

Now I want to get the sum of all these time in seconds.

I tried this: 
`$time_for_correct_ans = Testlog::where('token', $exists->token)->where('correct', 1)->sum('answering_time');`

But it took `00:01:29` as `129 seconds` which is wrong. Is there any better way to do it?

I'm using Laravel and MySQL.

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php and get seconds, add the result and ... you know the deal.

Comment: @NicolásCarlo Like this?
`$time_for_correct_ans = Testlog::where('token', $exists->token)->where('correct', 1)->sum(strtotime('answering_time'));`

Comment: You should store the time as integers (seconds) instead of strings.  Much easier to do arithmetic that way.

Comment: @Dave: is there any way with the correct structure?

Comment: I don't know laravel, but a guess: `->select('SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(answering_time))) as total')` might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MySQLs [`TIME_TO_SEC`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec):

```
$time_for_correct_ans = Testlog::selectRaw('SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(answering_time)) AS total')
                               ->where('token', $exists->token)
                               ->where('correct', 1)
                               ->pluck('total');
```